# How to get the tag leaders and tag bronze badges

Tags: support, badges, top-users, specialist-badge

I noticed that SO have the tag leaders and tag bronze badges, But I can't find them in [All Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page.

Why? and how to get the tag leaders and tag bronze badges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on a tag, there's a short information header at the top of the [page for that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).  There's a link there to the [tag leaders](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers).

There's a [tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) on the top right of the badges page.